# how to change default file path

Tags: android

my code is save images from gallery in default location /data/data/applicationname/files

if i change path in AppPhotos class to "/data/data/com.isummation.customgallery/files/";
 this is not show any image in list what do ido?? plz help me

```
 public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

 private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

 Cursor imagecursor;

 int image_column_index;

  Button selectBtn;

   ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

  DataBase db;

  Handler handle = new Handler(){         
  public void handleMessage(Android.os.Message message) {

    if (message.what == 1)
    {
        hideProgress();

        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) 
                      findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
    else if (message.what == 3)
    {
        hideProgress();

        AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this.finish();

    }
    else if (message.what == 2)
    {
        hideProgress();
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);   
 };
 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

  showProgress();
  new Thread() {
       public void run() { 
         try
        {
            loadFeed();
            android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
            alertMessage.what = 1;
            handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
            android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
            alertMessage.what = 2;
            handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);       
        }
    }
   }.start();


     selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
     selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        showProgress();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() { 
                 try
                {
                    SelecedtPhotos();
                    android.os.Message alertMessage = new  
     android.os.Message();
                    alertMessage.what = 3;
                    handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {   
                    android.os.Message alertMessage = new  
  android.os.Message();
                    alertMessage.what = 2;
                    handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);       
                }
            }
        }.start();


    }
   });

  }

    public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
 return outputStream.toByteArray();
   }

     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public ImageAdapter() {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)  
         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }

 public int getCount() {
    return count;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
 }

public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem,  
 null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView)  
  convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)   
 convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else 
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.checkbox.setId(position);
    holder.imageview.setId(position);

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
    {           
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            int id = cb.getId();

            if (thumbnailsselection[id])
            {
                cb.setChecked(false);
                thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                cb.setChecked(true);
                thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
            }
        }
    });

    /*holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
         {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id = v.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" +  
              arrPath[id]), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/

    holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
    holder.id = position;

    return convertView;
}
}
  class ViewHolder {
ImageView imageview;
CheckBox checkbox;
int id;
}

 public void loadFeed()
  {
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,  
          MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
           columns, null,null, orderBy);

 image_column_index =  
       imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

 this.count = imagecursor.getCount();

 this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];

 this.arrPath = new String[this.count];

 this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

 for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) 
  {
    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
    int dataColumnIndex =  
        imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    thumbnails[i] =  

    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext()
   .getContentResolver(), id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KI    ND, null);
    arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
  }

   imagecursor.close();
    }

   private void showProgress()
   {
    myProgressDialog =  
  ProgressDialog.show(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this,null, "Loading  
    Data...",        true); 
   }

    private void hideProgress()
  {
    if (myProgressDialog != null)
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
  }

   ///////////////////// Get File Name from path ////////////////////////////
  public String FileName(String path)
  {
  String f = " /";
  boolean c = false;

  for(int i=path.length()-1;i>0;i--)
   {
    if(c == false)
        if(path.charAt(i) == f.charAt(1))
        {
            c = true;
            return  
        path.substring(i+1,path.length());      
        }
   }

   return "";
}

    ///////////////////// Get Extension from path ////////////////////////////
 public String fileExt(String audio)
  {
String fileName = "";
String f = " .";
boolean c = false;

  for(int I=audio.length()-1;I>0;I--)
  {
    if(c == false)

        if(audio.charAt(I) == f.charAt(1))
        {
            fileName = audio.substring(I+1, audio.length());
            c = true;
        }
   }

     return fileName;
 }

   public void SelecedtPhotos()
   {

 final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
//  int cnt = 0;

for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
{
    if (thumbnailsselection[i])
    {
        //cnt++;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new 
      BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrPath[i],  
   options);

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream =  
      openFileOutput(FileName(arrPath[i]), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap));
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        db = new DataBase(getBaseContext()); 
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        db.insert_update("INSERT INTO Photos(name,ext,path)  
 VALUES  ('"+FileName(arrPath[i])+"','"+fileExt(arrPath[i])+"','"+arrPath[i]+"')");

        db.close();

        File file = new File(arrPath[i]);
        boolean t = file.delete();

    }
  }
  }
  }









       import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
      import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
        import android.widget.ListView;

          import com.database.DataBase;
          import com.isummation.customgallery.R;

                   public class AppPhotos extends Activity{

        ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

  ListView list;

  Activity activity = AppPhotos.this;

 List<AppPhotosData> picList;

  DataBase db;

  int position;

   Handler handle = new Handler(){ 
   public void handleMessage(Android.os.Message message) {

    if (message.what == 1)
    {
        hideProgress();

        list.setAdapter(new 
           AppPhotosAdapter(getApplicationContext(),activity,0,picList));
    }
    else if (message.what == 2)
    {
        hideProgress();
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);   
};
  };

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.photolist);

   list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
             int arg2, long arg3) {

        position = arg2;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  
               AlertDialog.Builder(AppPhotos.this);
        builder.setTitle("Hidden Photos");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to revert the  
         photo?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new  
         DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                    DialogBtn();
               }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new  
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();          
               }
        });
         AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
         dialog.show();

    }
  }); 

   showProgress();
   new Thread() {
        public void run() { 
            try
            {
                loadFeed();
                android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
                alertMessage.what = 1;
                handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {   
                android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
                alertMessage.what = 2;
                handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);       
            }
        }
    }.start();
 }

 private void showProgress()
  {
  myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AppPhotos.this,null, "Loading...",  
 true); 
}

    private void hideProgress()
 {
 if (myProgressDialog != null)
    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
}

 public void loadFeed()
{
 String filePaths = "/data/data/com.isummation.customgallery/files/";
 File outputFile1 = new File(filePaths);
 File[] files1 = outputFile1.listFiles();

 picList = new ArrayList<AppPhotosData>();

 for(File f:files1)
 {  
     AppPhotosData picObj = new AppPhotosData();

     Bitmap bmDulicated4 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());;

     picObj.setImage(bmDulicated4);
     picObj.setName(f.getName());

     picList.add(picObj);
 }
 }

  public void DialogBtn()
 {
db = new DataBase(getBaseContext()); 
try {
    db.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
 }

 Cursor DataC = db.selectQuery("SELECT path FROM Photos where name  
     ='"+picList.get(position).getName()+"'");

if(DataC.getCount() > 0)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = picList.get(position).getImage();

    if(picList.get(position).getImage() != null)
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new  
      FileOutputStream(DataC.getString(DataC.getColumnIndex("path")));
            outputStream.write(getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap));
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         File file = new File("/data/data/com.isummation.customgallery 
     /files/"+picList.get(position).getName());
         file.delete();

         showProgress();
         new Thread() {
                public void run() { 
                    try
                    {
                        loadFeed();
                        android.os.Message alertMessage = new  
  android.os.Message();
                        alertMessage.what = 1;
                        handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {   
                        android.os.Message alertMessage = new  
   android.os.Message();
                        alertMessage.what = 2;
                        handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);       
                    }
                }
            }.start();
    }
  }

   db.close();
 }

   public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }
   }
```

Comment: Do you have the `com.isummation.customgallery/files/` folder created? Why not try something like `customgallery/files/` to see if the points don't cause this regression?

Comment: i want to save images in my application internal memory

Comment: You should not hardcode the path in your app, since maybe some other phones doesn't have the same filesystem. Instead check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 1):

Manually create your app directory in sd card and then save image in that directory.
You can try following snippet.

```
                 String root=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                 File myDir = new File(root+"/demo_image");
                 if(!myDir.exists())
                 {
                     myDir.mkdir();
                 }

                 String fname = "Image"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
                 File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                 if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                 try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

Comment: is not helping me i want to crete directory inside application not on sd card

Comment: That's what `myDir.mkdir();` is for ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much!